# Закрыть блок Div при клике вне блока или на дате (datapicker)

Tags: javascript, css

На сайте календарь открывается по клику используется этот скрипт

```js
$('.datepicker').on('click', function() {
  $('.datepicker').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
});

$('ЧТО СЮДА ВСТАВИТЬ?').on('click', function() {
  $('.datepicker').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
});
```

и CSS

```css
.datepicker.close {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 40px;
  bottom: 5px;
  animation-name: DivClose;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.datepicker.open {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 260px;
  bottom: 5px;
  animation-name: DivOpen;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes DivOpen {
  from {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
  to {
    max-height: 260px;
  }
}

@keyframes DivClose {
  from {
    max-height: 260px;
  }
  to {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}
```

Что надо добавить в код, чтобы календарь закрылся после выбора даты или после клика вне календаря?

```html
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker close">
  <input type="hidden" id="datepicker_value" value=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $('.datepicker').on('click', function() {
        $('.datepicker').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
    });
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document).mouseup(function (e){
            var div = $(".datepicker");
            if (!div.is(e.target)
                && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $('.datepicker').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
    .datepicker {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datepicker">Пурум Пум Пум</div>
```

C изменениями:

```js
    $('.datepicker').on('click', function () {
        $('.datepicker').removeClass('close').addClass('open');
    });
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            var div = $(".datepicker");
            if (!div.is(e.target)
                && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $('.datepicker').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
            }
        });
        $('a.ui-state-default').on('click', function () {
            $('.datepicker').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
            }
        )
    });
```

Comment: Что-то не так... При выборе даты не убирается, а при клике вне блока вообще исчезает.

Comment: @MakarX изменил - проверьте. Или добавьте Вашу разметку, чтобы можно было сказать детальнее в чём причина конкретно у Вас.

Comment: Работает только клик вне блок, уже за это огромное спасибо. А при выборе даты документ загружает, но не убирается(

Comment: @MakarX надо просто видеть, как оформлен этот календарь и что можно отслеживать там при нажатии. Посмотрите в консоле, какой тег у даты, какие у него классы или id.

Comment: @MakarX А ещё лучше выложите код на codepen. Тогда можно будет помочь  сделать в точности так, как Вы хотите.

Comment: Что такое codepen? Календарь отсюда https://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: @MakarX это место куда Вы можете добавить свой код и сразу же проверить его работу. https://codepen.io/pen/ Просто сейчас с нуля устанавливать календарь и настраивать его - это длительный процесс. Никто этим заниматься не будет.

Comment: Денис. Я создам еще один вопрос позже, сейчас попробую разобраться с codepen. Еще раз большое спасибо.

Comment: @MakarX Посмотрел приблизительно теги. Попробуйте такой вариант `$('a.ui-state-default').on('click', function () {
    $('.datepicker').removeClass('open').addClass('close');
})` Предполагается что дата имеет тег `a` и класс `ui-state-default`

Comment: Это добавить к предыдущему коду или как? Может лучше создать новый вопрос? И да тег a имеет класс ui-state-default

Comment: @MakarX Главная задача помочь. Добавил в ответ в конце пример. Попробуйте. Если это тот-же календарь, должно сработать.

Comment: При повторном обращении не работает( Вопрос здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1080812/370904

Comment: @MakarX добавил там ответ - всё получилось?